# PHP with Crystal reports

Tags: php, crystal-reports

Can we use PHP with crystal report ?   I am actually looking for a drag and drop form designer kind of framework to be used in a web application.

Comment: Many duplicates, both related to what you ask in the title and to what you ask in the body: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+crystal+reports

Comment: possible duplicate of [Something like Crystal Reports for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747103/something-like-crystal-reports-for-php)