# php reporting tools

Tags: php, reporting, report

I have been developing with PHP for over ten years (since PHP version 3) and have used many different programming languages.

But I have never seen any PHP reporting tools. I am looking for something similar to

- Jasper Reports
- Crystal Reports
- Fast Report
- Quick Report
- Report Builder

I am *not* looking for:

- FPDF
- PHPExcel
- TCPDF

There must be a report designer and report library.

Has anyone seen PHP reporting tools comparable to those I mentioned?

Comment: @Starx programming language for report creating engine language must be php. there is solution using jasper report with java bridge. but its not php solution. its java solution

Comment: TCPDF is just great it needs some time to learn but does great results

Answer (score 12):

You should check out Php Reports http://jdorn.github.io/php-reports/

Pros:

- Display reports as HTML tables
- Add charts/graphs to accompany reports
- Export reports to CSV, XLS, JSON, XML, etc.
- Add parameters to reports (e.g. date range)
- Find reports by browsing or searching.
- Looks really nice.

Cons:

- No report designer, reports are just SQL files with comments for meta information
- No user management or access control
- No email scheduling of reports (coming soon)

I looked into all the existing solutions for PHP before writing the Php Reports framework. Everything out there was ugly, unmaintained, not flexible enough, and/or hard to set up and use.

Comment: No report designer is really a no go for most people

Comment: I don't think there's support for PostgreSQL, yet. Please confirm.

Comment: @jdorn hey mate does this php reports supports connection to the Oracle SQL Database?

Answer (score 9):

Well, judging by your example, you are looking for tools to represent the data. So, here are few you might like

- [Logi Report](http://www.freereporting.com/)
- [DataVision](http://datavision.sourceforge.net/)
- [Report manager](http://reportman.sourceforge.net/)
- [MySQL Reports](http://mysqlreports.com/)
- [myDBR](http://mydbr.com/) (Web Based)
- [i-net Clear Reports](http://www.inetsoftware.de/products/crystal-clear/designer)

---

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747103/something-like-crystal-reports-for-php) question to use Crystal Reports with php.

Comment: @markus-tharkun, May be he didn't have any reason.

Comment: Every downvote has a reason, even if he's a spastic and didn't actually want to downvote ;).

Comment: @Starx i am looking for engine is only php platform solution. If not i could used jasper report with javabridge. but if i do this user must be install java environment and other thing to run report platform

Comment: @sdemirkeser, Mysql Reports is PHP Platform solution. Haven't you checked my list?

Comment: @Starx all looked up all your list before. they are not report engine. i am looking for report engine and editor. If you checked my list such as Jasper Report or Crystal Report you could understand what i need

Answer (score 6):

Reportico looks promising. Also it has an extension for Yii making it my favourite.

http://www.reportico.org/site/index.php

Answer (score 2):

This project exist for long time. I create all my project using this.
http://www.simitgroup.com/?q=PHPJasperXML

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been a PHP dev for so long :P but I ran into the same issue.
So I developed a solution that is comparable with Report Builder.
It integrates several technologies (ApacheFOP, XSLT, XSLFO, MS Word, PHP, Doctrine 1.2) but provides a pure PHP API.

Take a look and count with my help if needed.
https://github.com/juanmf/sfPlugins/tree/master/reportPlugin

Currently its a symfony plugin, but I'll decouple it.

Its similar to ReportBuilder in that you use Word as designer for report templates, where you must consider the data source structure (XML) to create the data placeholders. Also if you get your data in an array, then you can convert it into XML directly with utils methods.
I explain a bit in this similar post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519024/report-engine-solution-for-lamp-application#13042656

Answer (score 0):

you can integrate PHP with Java and to use JasperReports with iReport as an IDE :).

I've developed a library this is the link https://github.com/FraGoTe/JasperPHPlibrary

Best regards.