# Any free Reporting Tool can read crystal report file?

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, reportviewer

I would like to migrate the reports from crystal reports to any free reporting tools. However, I don't want to rewrite the report in the new reporting tool. Are there any reporting tools which can read the crystal report files?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reporting tool that you are interesting in migrating to. Crystal Reports is one of the better tools for pixel perfect layouts and products out there are generally not comparable in the rich features available in CR.

Having said that, there are a not many results showing up on basic search. You might want to share more on the the kind of reporting solution you are intending to move to e.g. Is the intended tool a web control/toolkit or standalone reporting solution with scheduling etc.

The only tool that I could find is **Crystal Report to SSRS** (Yes SSRS is not free but assuming you have sql server this is bundled in for many editions). http://www.crystalmigrater.com/Default.aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. I have searched the free tools and there are a lot of options. e.g BIRT. Some of the other threads in stackoverflow also provides different reporting tools(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9646574/php-reporting-tools). However, there is no detail information whether the free tool can convert the crystal report files into their own format. The reason of migration is to reduce cost. Running a Linux Server is cheaper than Windows Server when the software needs upgrade. Usually the cloud services of Linux Server is more popular and cheaper than that of the Windows Server.

Comment: In fact my current system's report are not very complicated and therefore we don't need the fancy function of crystal report and the free reporting tools should be capable of doing the same job.

Comment: Maybe I cannot evade from rewriting all reports in the new reporting tools. Lol

Answer (score 0):

There is a free RPT file viewer from the vendor - http://www.crystalreports.com/crviewer-confirm