# report maker php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, report

I have been asked to find out if it is possible to connect Cyrstal Reports to a MYSQL database within a php website.

Is this possible?
Are their any alternatives

Comment: possible duplicate of [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/747103/something-like-crystal-reports-for-php]

Answer (score -1):

iReport is the best tool for mysql report generation in PDF, Excel HTML formats.
http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport