# Connect Crystal Report with php

Tags: php

I want to connect crystal report with php but it seems impossible. Is there any alternative report viewing tools like crystal for php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.dbfacephp.com could be solutions for you.
you can also relate it with
[Something like Crystal Reports for PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747103/something-like-crystal-reports-for-php)

Answer (score 6):

I think you can use [Reportico](http://www.reportico.org/swsite/site/home/index.php) 
Which is an opensource one.