# PHP wysiwyg Reporting tools

Tags: php, crystal-reports, report, reporting

I'm actually surprised I was looking bad or there really is no free and open!

My friends I looked everywhere on the web a wysiwyg reporting tools integrated with a 100% PHP application (ZEND FRAMEWORK, SYMPHONY, and others) but I can not find anything to help me.

I find the post about Crystal Report and PHP but apparently it fonctionnerai with Windows OS and what about Jasper Report integration - PHP seems that using a communication bridge JAVA PHP can reach a result?

So my question is this!

Is there really no free reporting tools that natively integrates PHP?

Thank you in advance for your feedback.

Comment: What about this: https://github.com/taq/phpreports/tree/master It may fit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different options available but I don't think there is a WYSIWYG tool. Please see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/747103/something-like-crystal-reports-for-php/747223#747223) for an extensive list of possibilities.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any free or open reporting tools on PHP, but there is a project that renders Jasper Reports natively on PHP (without the Java bridge you mention) and it's [PHPJasperXML](http://www.simitgroup.com/?q=PHPJasperXML), to use it, simply design your report on iReport and deploy the jrxml file that it generates.